# Is my data model suitable for the purpose?

Tags: core-data

I am fairly new to using CoreData. I have a class that stores basic coordinate information about points of interest, the code for this class is:

```
import Foundation
class StopAttributes: NSObject, NSCoding{
    var latitude: Double!
    var longitude: Double!
    var state: String!

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeDouble(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        aCoder.encodeDouble(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        aCoder.encodeObject(state, forKey: "state")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        latitude = aDecoder.decodeDoubleForKey("latitude")
        longitude = aDecoder.decodeDoubleForKey("longitude")
        state = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("state") as! String
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()

    }
}
```

I have an array of the class described above like so:

```
var unsortedStopsData: [StopAttributes] = [StopAttributes]()
```

Furthermore, I populate this array with around 3000 entries. I would like to save this array using CoreData. I have defined my data model like so:

[image]

Lastly, I made a subclass of my managed object class and within this class casted `unsortedStopsData` as `[StopAttributes]`to be able to save my array of `StopAttributes`.
My question is, am I designing the data model correctly? If not can you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Whether any data model is suitable for any purpose depends on how you want to use the data once you store it. Your model will store the data. Whether it works for how you need to use the data is a different question.

With a single transformable attribute, pretty much all you can do with Core Data is fetch every instance. You can't construct useful predicates, so you can't fetch a subset of the data. You can't, for instance, look for every instance where latitude and longitude are in a specific area. And you can't look up an instance by name. If that fits your needs, that's fine. But if your needs are so limited, you're getting almost no benefit from Core Data.

If you do need to fetch a subset of the data, then your Core Data entity must at a minimum have attributes for every value you'll use for filtering. Will you want to find instances based on latitude and longitude? If so, then they should be attributes.

Comment: From my understanding of your explanation, I need to add attributes for latitude, longitude, and state to my entity to be able to search for a specific instance of StopAttributes without fetching the entire array of 3000 values and looking through that, is that correct? If that is the case do I need to define anything in the relationships or fetched properties? My guess is to add some fetched properties.

Comment: If you need to use all three to filter data (not necessarily all at the same time), then yes, you need all three. You don't need relationships unless you have another entity that is related to this one somehow. Fetched properties are also probably not needed, at least based on your description of your requirements so far.